# Using bluez to access Bluetooth Low Energy devices?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I would like to connect to a Bluetooth Low Energy (BTLE, Bluetooth Smart) device using a linux box with bluez and a bluetooth dongle.  I have Orico BTA-402 dongle with CSR chipset; Ubuntu 14.04.  I figured out how to make it the dongle appear as a device to a phone (hciconfig hci0 leadv 3).

What I would like is the opposite, for the dongle/linux box to scan for devices, connect to a device, enumerate characteristics, and read/write them.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The hcitool lescan answer is incomplete. it will loop. You want a timeout, but a timeout that will not cause issue to hcitool (the default signal would)

For 5 seconds:

```
timeout -s SIGINT 5s hcitool -i hci0 lescan --passive
```

Then you can use gatttool:

```
sudo gatttool -i hci1 -b BC:6A:29:AC:2E:B4 -I
```

For more details on what to do after the connect: http://joost.damad.be/2013/08/experiments-with-bluetooth-low-energy.html

Answer (score 2):

Was demonstrated by [jaredwolff](http://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/get-started-with-bluetooth-low-energy/) you can use `hcitool`

```
hcitool lescan
```

Your device should show up like that: `F4:C7:F8:0A:BF:C9 TWI`. If don't show up, maybe it (the device that you are searching) isn't advertising itself.

---

To connect to a device you can use `gatttool` interative mode:

```
$ gatttool -I
[                 ][LE]> connect <BLE ADDRESS>
```

Inside `gatttool` you can use `char-desc` to obtain the available handles, `char-read-hnd` to read and `char-write-req` to write, see `help` to more details.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you post an example of a gatttool session that uses char-desc and char-write-req?

Comment: You can find one in the link: http://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/get-started-with-bluetooth-low-energy/
or 
https://learn.adafruit.com/reverse-engineering-a-bluetooth-low-energy-light-bulb/control-with-bluez

Comment: Also, is there a way to use gatttool for the same thing in non-interactive mode?

Comment: Yes, just remove the `-I` for non-interactive mode, and use the commands shown in `gatttool --help-gatt`.

Answer (score 1):

```
hciconfig hci0 up piscan
```

(assuming that 'hci0' is the device name for your bluetooth dongle)

The switch 'piscan' enables both 'pscan' and 'iscan'.

Excerpt from manpage:

> piscan Enable page and inquiry scan.
>
> noscan Disable page and inquiry scan.
>
> iscan  Enable inquiry scan, disable page scan.
>
> pscan  Enable page scan, disable inquiry scan.

Comment: That's for BlueTooth classic, no?  The question was about BlueTooth LE (also called BlueTooth Smart).